# Trying to capture events on vue.js 2, but without success

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, event-bus

I having a problem with capturing events with vue.js 2. I`m using a event bus to emit and capture the event.

In this block of code i wrote the function who will emit the event:

```
getLevelItems(parent) {
    this.$bus.$emit('get-level-items',{level: 'third', parent: parent})
},
```

In this other block i capture the event:

```
mounted() {
      this.$bus.$on('get-level-items', (obj) => {
        if (obj.level === 'third' && obj.parent === this.parent) {
          if (this.itemsNotFilled){
            this.getAllCategories(this.parent)
          }
        }
      })
    },
```

Ok, to emit the event with a button click, it`s working fine, but if i want to emit the event in another moment, example, after a request responds, the event will be emitted but will not be captured.

```
prepareData(data) {
        _.forEach(data, (value) => {
          value.selected = this.categories.includes(value._id) ? true : false
          value.show = this.categories.includes(value._id) ? true : false
          if (value.show){
            this.getLevelItems(value._id)
          }    
        })
        return data
      },
```

The eventbus.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const bus = new Vue()

export { bus }

export default function install (Vue) {
  Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$bus', {
    get () {
      return bus
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: The way your code reads, it looks like you attached a `bus` as a plugin to the Vue instance. Did you?

Comment: yes, i attached bus as plugin.

Comment: please provide that code as well

Comment: Also, instead of using an event bus, it might be easier to use `vuex`.

Comment: yes, i`m using vuex to other things, but for this i think it`s not necessary because it`s too simple... and shoud be working.

Comment: In your vue dev tools, can you see the event being fired?

Comment: yes, the event is fired, but the capture dosn`t execute.

Comment: And what about Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue() in main.js?

Answer (score -1):

Try using nextTick:

```
`mounted() { 
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.$bus.$on('get-level-items', (obj) => {
            if (obj.level === 'third' && obj.parent === this.parent) {
                if (this.itemsNotFilled) {
                    this.getAllCategories(this.parent)
                }
            }
         })
      })
  }`
```